# How to count closure calls

Tags: groovy, spock

How can I count closure method calls.

I have a closure as below:

```
 class SomeTestSpec extends Specification { 
  def greeting = { "Hello world!" } 

 @Unroll 
  def "test description"() { 
    given: // …. 
    when:
      def v = greeting then: // need something like that: 1 * greeting 
 } 
}
```

I call it once in the `when:` clause.

How can I test the call count (one in my case) in the `then:` clause.

Comment: Do you have a more complete example of what you're trying to test?  You have a class with a closure in it?  Or is this just a thought-experiment?

Comment: The closure in question is in the spec class, so I can't mock it...:

class SomeTestSpec extends Specification {
   def greeting = { "Hello world!" }

   @Unroll
   def "test description"() {
     given:
      // ….
      when:
      def v = greeting
      then:
       // need something like that: 1 * greeting 
    }
}

Comment: It would be better to edit your question, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), than to post in-line code in a comment. Please be advised to edit the question. :-)